# iterate over frames of video in openCV java

Tags: java, opencv, video, frame

I am trying to loop on frames video in openCV java 
here is my code

```
    Mat frame = new Mat();
    int numOfFrames = 0;
    boolean hasNext = true;
    while(hasNext){
        hasNext = video.read(frame);
        numOfFrames++;
    }
```

the problem is , it loops forever with no result or error or memory leak !
any help please

Comment: Are you reading from video file or capturing from camera?

Comment: yea, what lukk said. camera stream just *never* stops

Comment: reading from video file

Comment: Did you wait long enough to hit end of file? Maybe file is so large that it takes significant amount of time. If you have processing rate about 200fps, then decoding of 1 hour video on 25fps (90000 frames) takes 7,5 minutes to complete.

Comment: actually i am trying on 4 seconds video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop you coded needs some type of condition to break out the loop. As the code is now the while loop loops forever apparently.

So for instance you could do something like this to avoid an endless loop.

```
    boolean hasNext = true;
    while(hasNext) { 
        hasNext = video.read(frame);
        numOfFrames++;

        if(numOfFrames == 100) { 
              break;  // calling this will break out of the loop
        }
   } // end while loop
```

or you could simply add a `break;` but it will only iterate one time. Maybe a for loop is a better option? :D

Hope this helps.

That is cool there is a java wrapper for OpenCV. I have seen this program in a C programming book.

Comment: hmmm, she probably wanted the *end* of the movie, not an arbitrary number to bail out ..

Comment: Maybe that is the condition to use for the `break`?

Comment: @berak what is the condition to check to find the end of the video though? :D

Comment: hmm, i'm on 3.0, and exactly *that* happens here. the video( from file) ends, capture.read(frame); returns false. sarah seems to complain, that it's not happening as expected..

Comment: maybe you could have a condition to stop the program in the event the `video.read(frame);` never returns `false` ?

Comment: what is the condition to reach end of video ?that is my problem ,video.read(frame) doesn't return false

Comment: @SarahSami is there any type of event that you can check for each iteration of the loop as a sign that you have what you need and then exit the loop? Maybe have the program capture some arbitary number of frames and then ask the user if they want to keep capturing.

Comment: actually the processing is on all the video ,that code didn't work on 2.4.7 but works fine on 2.4.8 version .. thanks guys

Comment: http://cell0907.blogspot.com/2013/06/creating-windows-and-capturing-webcam.html @SarahSami I found a tutorial with a bunch of source code you could try. You are welcome about helping. OpenCV for java is interesting. :D

Comment: I'm not too familiar with OpenCV (yet) but wouldn't the logic behind this assume the video length to be 100 frames, or roughly 3.3 seconds of a 30fps video? Perhaps calculating the length of the video and frame rate dynamically could help you figure out when to set "hasNextFrame" to false to break the loop, instead of a hard-coded example